# Python overwriting my files and not finding others

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

So I'm making a game in Python and to save, there are player saves and autosaves. If I try to open a player save it says something like `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Legendary Forging/test.ini'` I can go to windows explorer and open that directory however.

When I open the autosave file it replaces whatever is in it with nothing. (I opened the file outside the program before during and after to check)

Here is my code:

```
import os
from random import randint
import time
import threading

class Engine(object):
    loop_condition = True
    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map
    def play(self):
        with open("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Legendary Forging\\autosave.ini", 'w') as player_save:
            player_save.close()
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        while self.loop_condition:
            print "\n--------"
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
            auto_save("")
            if next_scene_name == 'none':
                print
                self.loop_condition == False

class Player(object):
    hp = 100
    mana = 100
    exp = 0
    lvl = 1
    inventory = {}
    equipped = {}
    strength = 0
    intelligence = 0
    wisdom = 0
    dexterity = 0
    location = ""
    role = ""
    name = ""

class Commands(object):
    def determine(self, command):
        self.command = command
        help_word=""
        if command[0:4] == "exit":
            print
            time.sleep(.5)
            os._exit(1)
        elif command[0:4] == "save":
            create_save(command[4:])
            print "Your game has been saved under the name: %s" % command[4:]
        elif command[0:5] == "dance":
            print
            print "You dance in joy"
        elif command[0:4] == "help":
            for x in command[4:]:
                if x == " ":
                    del x
                else:
                    help_word += x
            if help_word == "warrior":
                print "\nwarrior description"
            elif help_word == "wizard":
                print "\nwizard description"
            elif help_word == "rogue":
                print "\nrogue description"
            elif help_word == "cleric":
                print "\ncleric description"
            else:
                print "There is no help file under that name."
        elif Player.location == 'startroom':
            if command[0:7] == "warrior":
                print
                print "You have chosen to be the Warrior."
                Player.strength +=10
                Player.wisdom +=2
                Player.dexterity +=6
                Player.hp +=20
                Player.intelligence +=0
                Player.mana += -100
                Player.role = "warrior"
            elif command[0:6] == "wizard":
                print
                print "You have chosen to be the Wizard."
                Player.strength +=0
                Player.wisdom +=6
                Player.intelligence +=10
                Player.dexterity +=2
                Player.hp += -20
                Player.mana +=50
                Player.role = "wizard"
            elif command[0:5] == "rogue":
                print
                print "You have chosen to be the Rogue."
                Player.strength +=4
                Player.wisdom +=4
                Player.intelligence +=2
                Player.dexterity +=10
                Player.hp +=0
                Player.mana +=-50
                Player.role = "rogue"
            elif command[0:6] == "cleric":
                print
                print "You have chosen to be the Cleric."
                Player.strength +=6
                Player.wisdom +=10
                Player.dexterity +=6
                Player.hp +=10
                Player.intelligence +=0
                Player.mana += 0
                Player.role = "cleric"
            elif command[0:4] == "load":
                if command[5:] == "autosave":
                    open_save("autosave")
                    print "Loaded autosave."
                else:
                    open_save(command[5:].lower())
                    print "Loaded save name: %s" % command [5:]

class Scene(object):
    def enter(self):
        print "Scene info"

class StartRoom(Scene):
    role_list = ["Warrior", "Rogue", "Wizard", "Cleric"]
    def enter(self):
        Player.location = "startroom"
        print "To load a previous games auto-save, type 'load autosave'\nTo load a custom save type 'load <save name>" 
        choice_load = raw_input(">")
        command_load = Commands()
        command_load.determine(choice_load)
        if Player.location != "startroom":
            return Player.location
        print"Welcome! What is your name?"
        choice_name = raw_input(">")
        self.choice_name = choice_name
        print "Choose one of the following roles."
        print "Type \"Help <role>\" to see more info about each role."
        print
        for x in self.role_list:
            print x
        print
        choice_role = raw_input(">")
        self.choice_role = choice_role.lower()
        Player.name = self.choice_name
        Player.role = self.choice_role
        command_room1 = Commands()
        command_room1.determine(self.choice_role) 
        if self.choice_role == "warrior" or self.choice_role == "wizard" or self.choice_role == "rogue" or self.choice_role == "cleric":
            time.sleep(.5)
            return "room1"
        else:
            return 'startroom'

class Death(Scene):
    quips = [
             "Wow. Much Death, so sad. Wow.",
             "Hah you suck at this!",
             "Try Again!",
             ]
    def enter(self):
        Player.location = "death"
        print Death.quips[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)]
        print
        print "Game Over"
        return 'none'

class Room1(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        Player.location = "room1"
        print "Room 1"
        choice_i = raw_input("\n >")
        choice=choice_i.lower()
        self.choice = choice
        if self.choice == "left" or self.choice == "l":
            return "death"
        elif self.choice == "right" or self.choice == "r":
            return "room2"
        else:
            command_room1 = Commands()
            command_room1.determine(self.choice) 
            time.sleep(.5)
            return "room1"

class Room2(Scene):
    def enter(self):
        Player.location = "room2"
        print "Room 2"

class Map(object):
    scenes = {
        'room1': Room1(),
        'death': Death(),
        'room2': Room2(),
        'startroom': StartRoom()
    }
    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene
    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        return Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
        Player.location = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

class Saving(object):
    savepath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Legendary Forging"
    global auto_save
    global open_save
    global create_save
    def create_dir(self):
        if os.path.exists("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Legendary Forging") == False:
           os.makedirs("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Legendary Forging")
    def create_save(save_name):
        with open("C:/Program Files (x86)/Legendary Forging/%s.ini" % (save_name), 'w') as player_save:
            player_save.close()
        with open("C:/Program Files (x86)/Legendary Forging/%s.ini" % (save_name), 'r+') as player_save:
            player_save.write(    #not sure how to do inventory or equipped yet
"""player.name = %s
player.role = %s
player.hp = %d
player.mana = %d
player.exp = %d
player.lvl = %d
strength = %d
intelligence = %d
wisdom = %d
dexterity = %d
location = %s""" % (Player.name, Player.role, Player.hp, Player.mana, Player.exp, Player.lvl, Player.strength, Player.intelligence, Player.wisdom, Player.dexterity, Player.location))
            player_save.close()
    def auto_save(self):
            with open("C:/Program Files (x86)/Legendary Forging/autosave.ini", 'w') as player_save:
                player_save.write(    #not sure how to do inventory or equipped yet
"""player.name = %s
player.role = %s,
player.hp = %d,
player.mana = %d,
player.exp = %d,
player.lvl = %d,
strength = %d,
intelligence = %d,
wisdom = %d,
dexterity = %d,
location = %s,""" % (Player.name, Player.role, Player.hp, Player.mana, Player.exp, Player.lvl, Player.strength, Player.intelligence, Player.wisdom, Player.dexterity, Player.location))
    def open_save(file_name):
        with open("C:/Program Files (x86)/Legendary Forging/%s.ini" % (file_name),"r") as player_save:
            print player_save.read
            player_save.close()

a_map = Map('startroom')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_save = Saving()
a_save.create_dir()
a_game.play()
```

Im not sure why it does this as it was working fine this morning. I think it changed after I changed the inputs for the filenames of saves to all lower case.

**EDIT**
I figured out I forget a pair of parenthesis after `print player_save.read`
I still cant load any other file except for the autosave file though

**EDIT** I found why it wouldn't load!

```
elif command[0:4] == "save":
            create_save(command[4:])
```

that 4 should be a 5, it was taking the space between load and the filename.

Comment: You'll have better luck here if you trim your program down to something small that still fails. That said, you forgot to add the "self" parameter to several of your methods, which is part of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Legendary Forging\\autosave.ini", 'w') as player_save:
    player_save.close()
```

I am not sure what you thought this block of code was doing, but what it does is open your file in overwrite mode (erasing existing contents), and then close it right away. I only glanced at your code briefly, but doing that at the start of the game every single time you start it seems like it isn't what you want to be doing?

Comment: Im not super competent with file creation **obviously**, I thought that created that file if it wasn't already there.

Comment: @user2963540: The code tries to close the file *twice*. The point of using `with`-statement in the first place is to close the file automatically.